# Array[Byte] does not take type parameters

Tags: scala, haskell

In Haskell, I can constraint a parameter to a type class, for example:

```
Prelude> f x y = x * y
Prelude> :t f
f :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

I was trying to do the same in `Scala` as following:

```
def sendMessage[A: Array[Byte], B: Array[Byte]](producer: Eval[KafkaProducer[A, B]])(pr: Eval[ProducerRecord[A, B]]) =
```

But the compiler complains:

```
[error] /home/developer/Desktop/scala/PureProducer/src/main/scala/TheProducer.scala:39:20: Array[Byte] does not take type parameters
[error]   def sendMessage[A: Array[Byte], B: Array[Byte]](producer: Eval[KafkaProducer[A, B]])(pr: Eval[ProducerRecord[A, B]]) =
```

How to constraint a type parameter in Scala?

Comment: I wonder how this is “the same”... seems to be two very different functions.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? `Array[Byte]` is not a type class. Are you trying to say that `A` and `B` must be equal to `Array[Byte]`? That'd be like doing `f :: (a ~ [Byte]) => a -> a -> a` in Haskell - you can do that with the right extensions, but it's pretty nonsensical since it's equivalent to `f :: [Byte] -> [Byte] -> [Byte]`, so why (pretend to) have the type variable at all?

Comment: What I want to do is, avoid writing type several times, like:  `sendMessage(producer: Eval[KafkaProducer[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]]])(pr: Eval[ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]]])`. As you can I see, I have to write `Array[Byte]` four times.

Comment: How to constraint, a type parameter to a typeclass in scala?

Comment: @zero_coding "How to avoid writing the same type name multiple times?" and "How to constraint a type parameter to a typeclass?" are two fundamentally different questions, which makes me think that you don't understand what `Num a => a -> a -> a` does in Haskell (it's not a shortcut for `Num -> Num -> Num`, which isn't even legal unless you define a type named `Num`). You constrain a type parameter to a typeclass using `[TypeParameter : TypeClass]`, but `Array[Byte]` is *not* a typeclass. To avoid typing, you can just use a type alias.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Scala type classes are represented as generic traits whose instances are passed as implicit parameters. As an example take the following Haskell type class:

```hs
class Foo a where
    foo :: a
    bar :: a -> a -> a

f :: Foo a => a -> a
f x = bar foo x

instance Foo Int where
    foo = 42
    bar x y = x + y

f 23 -- Result: 42 + 23 = 65
```

The Scala equivalent would look like this:

```scala
// class Foo a
trait Foo[A] {
    def foo: A
    def bar(x: A, y: A): A
}

def f[A](x: A)(implicit foo: Foo[A]) = foo.bar(foo.foo, x)

// instance Foo Int
implicit case object FooInt extends Foo[Int] {
    def foo = 42
    def bar(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
}

f(23) // Result: 42 + 23 = 65
```

There's also a shortcut to define the implicit parameter: `def f[A: Foo](x: A)` is short for `def f[A](x: A)(implicit _unnamed: Foo[A])`. However this means that you can't access the instance of the type class directly in the body (because you don't give it a name), so it's only useful when all you do is pass the type class instance around to other methods (which can be done implicitly and thus does not require a name).

In Scala the `Num` type class is called `Numeric` instead, which offers methods like `plus` and `times`. So to do the same thing as your Haskell example, you can write:

```
def f[A](x: A, y: A)(implicit num: Numeric[A]) = num.times(x,y)
```

---

The reason that your attempt with `Array[Byte]` did not work is because `Array[Byte]` is not a type class. Specifically the `A: Array[Byte]` shorthand expands to this:

```
def sendMessage[A, B](producer: Eval[KafkaProducer[A, B]])(pr: Eval[ProducerRecord[A, B]])(implicit _unamed1: Array[Byte][A], implicit _unnamed2: Array[Byte][B])
```

Looking at that it should be clear why that does not work: `Array[Byte][A]` just makes no sense.

According to your comments you simply want to avoid writing `Array[Byte]` multiple times. This has nothing whatsoever to do with type classes (neither in Haskell nor in Scala). You can simply use a type alias for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that always takes an Array, just constraint the inside type, and the types are equal, so you just need one type variable, and then the type you want to be subtype, I'm not sure if Byte can be subtyped so:

```
def sendMessage[A<:YourClass](producer: Eval[KafkaProducer[Array [A]])(pr: Eval[KafkaProducer[Array [A]]) =...
```

But I think you can just do in your case:

```
def sendMessage(producer: Eval[KafkaProducer[Array [Byte]])(pr: Eval[KafkaProducer[Array [Byte]]) =...
```

Comment: The `Byte` class if final, so there can't be any subclasses of it. So you might as well do `sendMessage(producer: Eval[KafkaProducer[Array[Byte]])(pr: Eval[KafkaProducer[Array[Byte]])`